# Custom crop method isn't working in iPhone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iphone

Im facing this STRANGEST issue in my website. The method given below takes a base64 string and the crop, zoom and rotation values and returns a modified base64 string. This method works absolutely fine on all the android devices and desktops. But when an iPhone is used, this methods returns a base64 string that when converted is a plain black image. I have no clue why its behaving like this on all the iPhones.

Extra info : This only happens for the HEIF images that are automatically converted to jpeg when a user selects them from the iPhone's gallery. For other formats like jpg and png the method works fine even on iPhone.

Here's the crop method

```
async function getCroppedImg(imageSrc, pixelCrop, rotation) {

        console.log('imagesrc : ', imageSrc)
        const image = await createImage(imageSrc);
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        const maxSize = Math.max(image.width, image.height);
        const safeArea = 2 * ((maxSize / 2) * Math.sqrt(2));
        canvas.width = safeArea;
        canvas.height = safeArea;

        ctx.translate(safeArea / 2, safeArea / 2);
        ctx.rotate(getRadianAngle(rotation));
        ctx.translate(-safeArea / 2, -safeArea / 2);
        ctx.drawImage(
            image,
            safeArea / 2 - image.width * 0.5,
            safeArea / 2 - image.height * 0.5
        );

        const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, safeArea, safeArea);
        canvas.width = pixelCrop.width;
        canvas.height = pixelCrop.height;

        ctx.putImageData(
            data,
            0 - safeArea / 2 + image.width * 0.5 - pixelCrop.x,
            0 - safeArea / 2 + image.height * 0.5 - pixelCrop.y
        );

        // As Base64 string
        return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    }
```

```
const createImage = (url) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const image = new Image();
            image.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(image));
            image.addEventListener("error", (error) => reject(error));
            image.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
            image.src = url;
        });

function getRadianAngle(degreeValue) {
        return (degreeValue * Math.PI) / 180;
    }
```

Comment: Some more info is needed. Which iPhone browser are you experiencing this issue in? It could be that that browser cannot convert HEIF to jpg as expected

Comment: @chef i confirmed it. The browser converts them to jpeg. Then the jpeg is converted to a valid base64 string but this method returns the string that's black when converted to image.

Comment: Is it Safari? Chrome? Firefox?